# Program for generating files?

Tags: windows, file

Not sure if this belongs on Stack, SuperUser or ServerFault, so feel free to migate as best fits.

I am testing a web service that sends out files, because of this I need to find a way to automatically create files. Does anyone know of a free file generation tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use fsutil to do so

The Syntax is:

fsutil file createnew C:\testfile.txt 1000

Answer (score 4):

Try `$ /dev/random > myfile1` with different time lengths and namings

Comment: Running Windows :) And don't easily have access to a Linux box atm, wish I did though.

Comment: turning a windows box into a linux box isn't hard at all

Comment: It's just a matter of reinstalling. Although setting up the GNU environment in Windows is probably what you meant. :o)

Answer (score 0):

You can test your webservice by hard with:

[JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/)

It is more automated than doing it by hand and it has a lot of nice monitoring features.